# Lagrange inversion theorem: from local to global solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a nonzero analytic function $\zeta\in\mathcal{A}\mapsto f(\zeta)\in\mathbb{C}$ in some open connected subset of the complex plane, and consider the equation $f(\zeta)=z$ for some $z\in f(\mathcal{A})$. Fix $\zeta_0\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $f'(\zeta_0)\neq0$: then the Lagrange inversion theorem ensures that there exists a neighborhood $I_0$ of $f(\zeta_0)$ and an analytic function
\begin{equation}
z\in I_0\mapsto g_{\zeta_0}(z)\in\mathcal{A}
\end{equation}
which is a local inverse of $f(\zeta)$.

Repeating the same procedure for another point $\zeta'_0\in\mathcal{A}$, we can find a neighborhood $I'_0$ of $f(\zeta'_0)$ and an analytic function
\begin{equation}
z\in I'_0\mapsto g_{\zeta'_0}(z)\in\mathcal{A}
\end{equation}
as before. In particular, if $\zeta_0$ and $\zeta'_0$ are sufficiently close, the sets $I_0$ and $I'_0$ intersect and hence $g_{\zeta_0}$ and $g_{\zeta'_0}$ are each an analytic continuation of the other.

Through this procedure, if $f(\zeta)$ has nonzero derivative in the whole region, we should be able to extend $g_{\zeta_0}$ to a function in the whole $f(\mathcal{A})$, corresponding to the inverse function of $f$. Is this argument correct? What happens if we allow $f'$ to have zeros? Can we still construct globally defined "inverses" of $f$ through the procedure above? Is the number of such functions linked to the number of zeros of $f'$?